# How can I find the number of word matches within a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell (B) that contains the following URL:
https://www.solicitors.co.uk/what-is-on-police-bail-but-not-charged/

I have another cell (A) a that contains a search query:
police bail without charge uk

I want to create a formula (C) that counts the number of words from A that also appear in B.

In this example, the result should = 2: police, bail

I suspect this may not be possible in a formula and may require a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this pattern:

```
=counta( 
  iferror( 
    filter( 
      transpose( split(A2, "/- .", true) ), 
      match( 
        transpose( split(A2, "/- .", true) ), 
        transpose( split(B2, "/- .", true) ), 
        0 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

With the sample values you quote, the formula will give a result of `3`, because there are three words that match: "police", "bail" and "*uk*".

Comment: You, my friend, are a genius! Works perfectly. Many, many thanks

Comment: Done - thanks for the info